# Help at installing elementary OS

Tags: system-installation, boot

When I click "Try elementary OS without installing" or "install elementary OS" my computer boots to Windows 7.

I have burned the elementary OS ISO in my USB.

Answer (score 2):

Just check a few things.

1. Enter BIOS and disable Secure boot
2. Enable USB boot
3. Set Boot Priority to USB by default

Installation:

1. Boot your USB and complete basic setup until you reach partition manager. Select the last option "Something else" to proceed with partition manager.
2. In partition manager,

   - Select free space, and create a primary 20000MB partition as root denoted by / marked at beginning of space.
   - Select free space, and create a logical 4000MB partition as swap area from dropdown marked at beginning of space.
   - Select free space, and create remaining space as a logical partition for home denoted by /home marked at beginning of space.
3. IMPORTANT..! Select the Windows Boot manager partition (EFI) from the drop down at the end of partition of table. And then click INSTALL.
4. Click Next and complete the setup. You will recieve a dialog box as REBOOT once installation completes. Just reboot and unplug your USB media.

Enjoy Elementary Loki..!

IF IT STILL ENTERS INTO WINDOWS

Enter into BIOS and change the order of OS Boot manager to Ubuntu/Elementary as default. It should now load the Linux grub loader.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me that there are a problem with the usb you created. Try to redownload the iso and make again the bootable usb.

Comment: I did it 3 times

Answer (score 0):

Try burning the usb image using Rufus 
https://rufus.akeo.ie/

It is a good usb burning tool and does all the important works for you. And check is your image of elementary is not corrupted. You can verify the hash of the file.

Comment: I burned my usb with Rufus and i had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make sure that you have your USB defined as booting device prior to HDD.
   I don't know which PC model you're running, so it might vary, but the idea is the same.
2. You need to disable secure boot in bios
3. If you are running RAID you need to change it to AHCI in the bios

let me know whats your pc model

Also [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_EFI_or_Legacy_mode) might help you to understand the whole process

Answer (score -1):

Try using universal usb installer for making a bootable usb:
https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/